# How to give ifdef variable in terminal in makefile

Tags: makefile, conditional-compilation

- When compiling with “make xxx=0”, the message displayed on the terminal is not displayed, but when compiling with “make xxx=1”, a message about the build process is displayed on the terminal window when compiling.

$make xxx=1
gcc
gcc
..
..

$make xxx=0
$

Comment: First, please format your question properly so we can understand it it (it's a good idea that you re-read your question after you post it and if it has formatting issues, you use the "Edit" option to fix them--you can also just look at the preview of your question).

Comment: Second, we can't help without seeing your makefile (again please cut and paste and format so it's readable) or understanding what it is that this `xxx=1` / `xxx=0` is supposed to do.  And lastly, please put a clear statement of your issue in the message, not just the title.  What exactly is it that you want to happen, that is not happening now?  Then, we can help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.